# Treat expressions as numbers in Maple

Tags: maple

I write some code of procedure that contains next 2 lines. 
Why line 2 isn't executed? How to force Maple treat all math expressions as numbers?

```
b := evalf(sqrt(5)); 
k := evalf(ceil(Log2(ceil(sqrt(b)))));

                        b := 2.236067977
                       k := ceil(Log2(2))
```

[image: Issue]

Comment: Querying Maple's Help system reveals immediately that there is no `Log2` command. Doing a search in the Help system should precede asking a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Maple contains log2 function in MTM package. To use logarithm with base b you should call `log[b](x)` function.